# Can i include the website url in the generated vue bundle references in the index.html for a true absolute path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, path, reverse-proxy, vue-cli-3

I'm currently working on a vue.js single page app that will be put behind a reverse proxy, and one of the questions I got is if I could make the paths in my index.html absolute.

As an example, a vue build currently generates the script tags as follows:
`src=/js/chunk-vendors.04f9c437.js`
I want my URL to be generated in that path like so:
`src=https://myapp.com/js/chunk-vendors.04f9c437.js`

I've looked through the vue.js configurations but I could only find the `publicPath` option, which works but also messes up my routing (so it does more then I want).

Any ideas or input on how to go about this? I could simply write an extra script to replace the paths after each build, but I'd like to do this in a more elegant way if possible.

Comment: maybe with `assetsDir`? the default is `''`

Comment: `assetsDir` seems to work but it also adds a `/` in front of the path